# How to Display more than one Rich:DataTable in single page?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I want to display dynamic number of rich data tables in one page based on data so what i am doing is, within c:foreach looping ui:include which points to datatable.xhtml.but as result i am getting only one data table.any solution will be appreciated..

sample code :

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="item">
<ui:include src="/dataTable.xhtml" >
<ui:param name="values" value="#{item.value}" />
<ui:param name="some other values" value="#{item.key}" />
</ui:include>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `c:forEach`, use JSF components for looping instead. For example `rich:dataGrid`:

```
<rich:dataGrid columns="3" var="res" value="#{chProfile.clubItems}">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:300px;">
        <rich:dataTable style="width: 100%">
            <rich:column id="item">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{res.promoName} Club" />
                </f:facet>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
        <h:outputText value="#{res.freeItemsReceived} free #{res.freeItemsReceived == 1 ? 'item' : 'items'} received during this calendar month" /><br />
    </h:panelGroup>
</rich:dataGrid>
```

Other alternative can be `ui:repeat`:

```
<ui:repeat var="state" value="#{referenceLists.USstates}">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{reportForm.isChStateSelected(state.value)}">
        <h:outputText value="#{state.label}" /><br />
    </ui:fragment>
</ui:repeat>
```